# how to get the arrival time of push notification in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

Present I am working in Remote Push notification service. I have a some problem i.e, how to get the arrival time of push notification. Check the below image[image]

Is it passable? Any one help me...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The time the app received can be easily recorded this way.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
       didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo {

    NSDate *appReceiptTime = [NSDate date];
```

The time the server sent can be included as a custom field in the push request like this:

> { "sentAt": "2013-01-01 11:00:00 +0000" }

...and found in userInfo under the key @"sentAt"

When did the device receive the notification?  I am unaware of a way to get that.  Do you need that accurately?  The send time could be a decent approximation... maybe even made better by fudging it forwards 3-5sec.